# Can't view all the extra part when scaling in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, view, interface-builder

I'm working on Xcode 4 and I'm facing a problem when scaling the UIScrollView as an example. If the UIScrollView becomes larger than its current parent window, I can't see its extra part.

It wasn't like that in the older Xcode versions.

Do you know how to fix this?